# How to split arguments in the context of `expl3`[, not `xparse`]?

Tags: expl3, arguments

I'm trying to do something like `SplitArgument{<sep>}` within `expl3`. For now I fix `<sep>=;`. I didn't get very far:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_inner:nnn{(#1)(#2)(#3)}

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_outer:n
{
%  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; }{#1}

%\seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_seq{,}{,}{,} % EXPECT a,b,c % OK

%\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq{(##1)} % EXPECT (a)(b)(c) % OK

%wishful thinking?
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf
  \__erw_inner:nnn
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq{\exp_not:n{{##1}}}
  }
} %WANT: \erw_inner:nnn{a}{b}{c} % GET: ERROR: You can't use a prefix with `the character )'

\NewDocumentCommand\Test{m}
{
  \__erw_outer:n{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\Test{a;b;c}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should explain what's your aim: do you want that `\Test{a;b;c;d;e;f}` outputs `(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)`? Independently on how many semicolon separated items you specify?

Comment: Also, @Erwann seems to expect that the `f` argument of `\exp_last_unbraced:Nf` will make `\seq_map_inline:Nn` do its job before the whole is unbraced, however `\seq_map_inline:Nn` is *not fully expandable* (there is no star where it is documented), therefore an `f` argument can't make it work. `\seq_map_inline:Nn` needs to be used in a place where expansion + execution happen; expansion-only isn't enough.

Comment: As stated inside the code, I want `__outer:n{a;b;c}` to output `__inner:nnn{a}{b}{c}`.

Comment: I was hoping `\__erw_inner:nnn\__xparse_split_argument:nnn{2}{;}{#1}` would work insider `__erw_outer:n`. The reason I need `expl3` rather than `xparse` is for argument expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand why you have the "helper functions" `\__erw_inner:nnn` and `\__erw_outer:N` but I assume that this is part of the real application you have in mind. It seems to me that you are misusing the expl3 syntax: when you use

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; }{#1}
```

to split the input then you can process the data in `\l_tmpa_seq` using the tools that expl3 provides. In particular, I do not understand why you have `\exp_last_unbraced:Nf` in your code.

To get the desired output you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{m}
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; }{#1} % split the input
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {(##1)}   % print bracket enclosed input 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \Test{a;b;c}

\end{document}
```

If this doesn't fit your use-case can you give more information about what you are really trying to do?

Note that the `\ExplSyntaxOff` should go at the end of the expl3 macro definitions. If it is at the end of the document, as in the MWE, then all of the special expl3 characters will be unusable in your document.

Comment: As stated inside the code, I want `\erw_outer:n{a;b;c}` to output `\erw_inner:nnn{a}{b}{c}`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not trying to do what `\SplitArgument` does. This preprocessor wants *two* arguments: a number and a separator. The number is essential.

If you do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{;}}m } {...#1...}
```

then you can trust that `#1` will be passed as *three* braced groups. Thus

```
\test{a;b;c}
\test{a;b}
\test{a}
```

will pass, respectively,

```
{a}{b}{c}
{a}{b}{-NoValue-}
{a}{-NoValue-}{-NoValue-}
```

The argument should not be empty.

Of course the replacement text for `\test` will contain something like

```
...\Command#1...
```

where `\Command` is a three-argument command that will test whether each one is `-NoValue-` by means of the `\IfNoValueTF` test.

If the argument to `\test` contains more than two semicolons you'll get an error, because the macro `\Command` would not be able to sensibly cope with four braced groups following it.

Your aim seems to be much more alike `\SplitList`. Let's say you have

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitList{;}}m } { ... }
```

Then the replacement text ought to contain something like

```
\ProcessList{#1}{\Command}
```

where `\Command` is a one-argument macro, to which each item in the list will be passed one after the other. So, for instance,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{\SplitList{;}}m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\Command}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Command}{m}{(#1)}
```

a call such as

```
\test{a;b;c;d;e}
```

will result in the output

> (a)(b)(c)(d)(e)

There is no limit to the number of semicolon separated items, but again the argument should not be empty.

**Example**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testA}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{;}}m }{%
  \CommandA#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CommandA}{mmm}{%
  #1--%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{???}{#2}--%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{???}{#3}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testB}{ >{\SplitList{;}}m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\CommandB}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CommandB}{m}{%
  (#1)%
}

\begin{document}

Here we look at \verb+\SplitArgument+

\testA{a;b;c}\par
\testA{a;b}\par
\testA{a}\par

\bigskip

Here we look at \verb+\SplitList+

\testB{a;b;c;d;e}\par
\testB{a;b;c;d}\par
\testB{a;b;c}\par
\testB{a;b}\par
\testB{a}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

What if you want to emulate the latter behavior?

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__erwann_parens:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__erwann_parens:n { (#1) }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: sorry for having misled you. I acknowledged "This preprocessor wants two arguments" by saying "For now I fix <sep>=;". The only reason I use xparse is for `\Test`.

Comment: @Erwann But this leaves open the question: what do you want to do if there are less (or more) than two semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

As stated inside the code given in the question, I want `\__erw_outer:n{a;b;c}` to output `\__erw_inner:nnn{a}{b}{c}` which necessitates something like `\SplitArgument`. I should have added that the motivation for this is to be able to do argument expansion on the outer's argument. Here's a lousy solution that goes back and forth between `expl3` and `xparse`. Everything should be in `expl3` (perhaps `\__xparse_split_argument:nnn`?)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_inner:nnn{(#1)(#2)(#3)}

\NewDocumentCommand\ErwOuter
  {> { \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m }
{
  \__erw_inner:nnn#1
}

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_outer:n
{

\ErwOuter{#1}

} %WANT: \erw_inner:nnn{a}{b}{c} 

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__erw_outer:n {e}

\NewDocumentCommand\Test{m}
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{#1} 
  \__erw_outer:n{\l_tmpa_tl}\\
  \__erw_outer:e{\l_tmpa_tl}
}

\begin{document}

 \Test{a;b;c}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image: Screen]