# Argument splitting using low-level Expl3 syntax

Tags: expl3, forest, xparse, tikz-qtree, qtree

Using `egreg`'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669975/262813) I tried to create my own advanced command with `key=value`-style optional argument splitting, which was successful.

Now how can I integrate the splitting of the **mandatory** argument, i.e. have

```
\mycoolcommand[...,...,...]{arg1,arg2}
```

instead of

```
\mycoolcommand[...,...,...]{arg1}{arg2}
```

?

In the MWE below, the command I seek would be:

```
\newcoolbrace[...,...,...]{polp,root}
```

I usually use `\SplitArgument`, but I guess this will be a bit different here.

I know this might be a duplicate of [How to split arguments in the context of `expl3`[, not `xparse`]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524186/how-to-split-arguments-in-the-context-of-expl3-not-xparse;) but since I am not familiar with `Expl3` syntax, it is quite difficult for me to adapt the answer to my example.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text}



\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbraceaux}{mmmmm}{
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=#1pt}](#4)--(#5);
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={raise=#2pt,text along path,text align=center,text=#3}](#4)--(#5);}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbrace}{O{}mm}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace } { #1 }
    \krebs_newcoolbrace:VVVnn
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl
    {#2}
    {#3}
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace }
{
    braise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl,
    traise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl,
    text .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl,
    braise .initial:n = 36,
    traise .initial:n = 54,
    text .initial:n = ~,
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn \newcoolbraceaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn { VVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [nP[~][n
    [n][asp
    [~][asp
    [asp][pol,name=polp
    [~][pol
    [pol][vP
    [\textit{x},name=v][v′
    [v][root,name=root]]]]]]]]]
    \newcoolbrace[braise=26,traise=44,text=Unaccusative]{polp}{root}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure that `\newcoolbrace[…]{x,y}` is clearer than `\newcoolbrace[…]{x}{y}`. The two arguments are both required and they should follow a precise order, so they’re best kept separate.

Comment: You should use `text={#3}` instead of `text=#3` or else your text can't contain a comma or equals sign (at least without an additional set of braces).

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for this, I for sure need spaces and might need commas so it is really good to know!

Comment: @egreg I see what you mean but I tend to "simplify" every command I have, because from my perspective at least, accumulation of curly brackets makes the code uselessly heavy.

Comment: You can change your `\newcoolbrace` to `\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbrace}{O{}m}` and then replace your `{#2}` and `{#3}` with `{\clist_item:nn {#2}{1}}` and `{\clist_item:nn {#2}{2}}` respectively.

Comment: @ScottH. seems wasteful and requires to change the underlying internal macro in addition to the document level. Imho, `\SplitArgument` should be preferred.

Comment: In this particular case, you could just have `forest` split the argument (but I realise that's not a general solution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text}



\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbraceaux}{mmm>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
  \newcoolbraceauxa{#1}{#2}{#3}#4%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbraceauxa}{mmmmm}{%
  \draw[
    decorate,
    semithick,
    decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=#1pt},
  ](#4)--(#5);%
  \draw[
    decorate,
    semithick,
    decoration={
      raise=#2pt,
      text along path,
      text align=center,
      text={#3},
    },
  ](#4)--(#5);%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbrace}{O{}m}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace } { #1 }
    \krebs_newcoolbrace:VVVnn
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl
    \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl
    {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\keys_define:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace }
  {
    braise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl,
    traise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl,
    text .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl,
    braise .initial:n = 36,
    traise .initial:n = 54,
    text .initial:n = ~,
  }

\cs_set_eq:NN \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn \newcoolbraceaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn { VVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [nP[~][n
    [n][asp
    [~][asp
    [asp][pol,name=polp
    [~][pol
    [pol][vP
    [\textit{x},name=v][v'
    [v][root,name=root]]]]]]]]]
    \newcoolbrace[braise=26,traise=44,text=Unaccusative]{polp,root}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

However, I'm not sure this is better than the previous version with two mandatory arguments as the two arguments mean different things (the start node and the end node).

A different strategy could be to add them to the list of key-value pairs, with the difference that the keys `start` and `end` *must* be specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbraceaux}{mmmmm}{%
  \draw[
    decorate,
    semithick,
    decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=#1pt},
  ](#4)--(#5);%
  \draw[
    decorate,
    semithick,
    decoration={
      raise=#2pt,
      text along path,
      text align=center,
      text={#3},
    },
  ](#4)--(#5);%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbrace}{m}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace } { #1 }
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
      { \quark_if_nil_p:V \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_start_tl }
      { \quark_if_nil_p:V \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_end_tl }
      {
       \msg_error:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace } { missing-bounds }
      }
      {
        \krebs_newcoolbrace:VVVVV
          \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl
          \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl
          \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl
          \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_start_tl
          \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_end_tl
      }
    \group_end:
  }
\keys_define:nn { krebs/newcoolbrace }
  {
    braise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_braise_tl,
    traise .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_traise_tl,
    text .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_text_tl,
    start .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_start_tl,
    end .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_newcoolbrace_end_tl,
    braise .initial:n = 36,
    traise .initial:n = 54,
    text .initial:n = ~,
    start .initial:n = \q_nil,
    end .initial:n = \q_nil,
  }

\cs_set_eq:NN \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn \newcoolbraceaux
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \krebs_newcoolbrace:nnnnn { VVVVV }

\msg_new:nnnn { krebs/newcoolbrace } { missing-bounds }
  {
    Missing~start~or~end
  }
  {
   You~must~specify~'start=<label>'~and~'end=<label>'
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [nP[~][n
    [n][asp
    [~][asp
    [asp][pol,name=polp
    [~][pol
    [pol][vP
    [\textit{x},name=v][v'
    [v][root,name=root]]]]]]]]]
    \newcoolbrace{braise=26,traise=44,text=Unaccusative,start=polp,end=root}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Now the whole argument is mandatory, because there must be both `start` and `end`. Try omitting one of them and you'll see the error message popping out.

[image]

Comment: I removed the second mandatory argument in the definition of `\newcoolbrace` (the 2nd `m` and the `{#3}`, see `Sašo Živanović`'s correction here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672412/262813).

Answer (score 4):

This answer is more or less identical to @egreg's, namely it uses `\SplitArgument`, but it also uses `expkv-cs` for the key=value argument. Setting up your key=value interface if all you want to use it for is to forward the values to another macro is a lot easier with it.

After the definition of `\newcoolbracekv` with `\ekvcSplitAndForward` all the keys are turned into arguments for `\newcoolbraceaux` in the order the keys were specified.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoolbraceaux}{mmmmm}{
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=#1pt}](#4)--(#5);
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={raise=#2pt,text along path,text align=center,text={#3}}](#4)--(#5);}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\NewDocumentCommand\newcoolbrace { O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
  {\newcoolbracekv{#1}#2}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\newcoolbracekv\newcoolbraceaux
  {
     braise = 36
    ,traise = 54
    ,text = {} % defaults to an empty value
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [nP[~][n
    [n][asp
    [~][asp
    [asp][pol,name=polp
    [~][pol
    [pol][vP
    [\textit{x},name=v][v′
    [v][root,name=root]]]]]]]]]
    \newcoolbrace[braise=26,traise=44,text=Unaccusative]{polp,root}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your package seems to simplify life quite a lot. I'm for now trying to process and assimilate the standard way and I don't want to mix things up, but after a while and when the next version is out, I'm sure I'll have fun messing around with it. Thanks ;)