# Can't make a list of keys work

Tags: chapters, expl3, key-value

I am trying to make my own chapter-heading formatting command, using a `key=value` approach:

```
\coolchap[
chapstyle=<chapter-word formatting>,
titlestyle=<chapter-title formatting>,
befchap=<vspace before chapter-word>,
afchap=<vspace after chapter-word>,
aftitle=<vspace after chapter-title>]
```

But something must be wrong, because it has no effect: I receive no error message, but the values are being just ignored.

Note that the same happens if I define the argument as obligatory instead, then pass the command `\coolchap{key1=value1,key2=value2...}`.

The auxiliary command itself, i.e. `\chapterformat`, works.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{moresize}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterformat}{mmmmm}{%
    \ifdef{\chapter}{%
        \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
            \vspace*{#3\p@}% Vertical Space before "Chapter X" (50)
            {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \reset@font
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                {#1 \@chapapp{} \thechapter} % Chapter-word formatting.
                \par
                \vskip #4\p@ % Vertical Space after "Chapter X" (20)
                \fi
                {#2 ##1} % Title formatting.
                \par\nobreak
                \vskip #5\p@}} % Vertical Space after Chapter Title (180)
    }{}
}

\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn


\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xcoolchap:nnnnn { VVVVV }
\cs_set_eq:NN \xcoolchap:nnnnn \chapterformat

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolchap}{o}
{
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { coolchap } { #1 }
      \xcoolchap:VVVVV
        \xcoolchap_chapstyle
        \xcoolchap_titlestyle
        \xcoolchap_befchap
        \xcoolchap_afchap
        \xcoolchap_aftitle
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn { coolchap }
{
    chapstyle .tl_set:N = \xcoolchap_chapstyle,
    titlestyle .tl_set:N = \xcoolchap_titlestyle,
    befchap .tl_set:N = \xcoolchap_befchap,
    afchap .tl_set:N =  \xcoolchap_afchap,
    aftitle .tl_set:N = \xcoolchap_aftitle,
    chapstyle .initial:n = \HUGE\bfseries,
    titlestyle .initial:n = \Huge\bfseries,
    befchap .initial:n = 50,
    afchap .initial:n = 20,
    aftitle .initial:n = 180,
}



\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
    

    \coolchap[aftitle=360,befchap=100,afchap=40,chapstyle=\HUGE\itshape]
    
    \chapter{essai}
    
    XXX
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes on your code:

- use `\par` within the group in which font changes are applied, so instead of `{\huge Title string}\par` use `{\huge Title string\par}` or else the interline spacing will end up wrong.
- you had a few unwanted spaces in your definition, note that a space after `#1` in your definition is not ignored, even if `#1` will be `\huge` or something like that at use time.
- your variables aren't following `expl3` naming conventions, I suggest you correct this (those conventions are there for a reason, even if there is no sane way to make TeX enforce them).

I didn't correct all of those in each code block, so don't just copy these 1:1 but pay attention where you need to fix them.

---

The issue is that you redefine `\@makechapterhead` inside of a group and the definition is lost at its end. You have to make the redefinition after `\group_end:`, you could do this like the following. Also, your `\coolchap` macro does throw an error if you omit the optional argument, you should use `O{}` instead of `o` like in the following.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{moresize}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterformat}{mmmmm}{%
    \ifdef{\chapter}{%
        \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
            \vspace*{#3\p@}% Vertical Space before "Chapter X" (50)
            {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \reset@font
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                {#1 \@chapapp{} \thechapter} % Chapter-word formatting.
                \par
                \vskip #4\p@ % Vertical Space after "Chapter X" (20)
                \fi
                {#2 ##1} % Title formatting.
                \par\nobreak
                \vskip #5\p@}} % Vertical Space after Chapter Title (180)
    }{}
}

\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn


\tl_new:N \l__xcoolchap_redefinition_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolchap}{O{}}
{
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { coolchap } { #1 }
      \tl_set:Nx \l__xcoolchap_redefinition_tl
        {
          \exp_not:N \chapterformat
            { \exp_not:V \l__xcoolchap_chapstyle_tl }
            { \exp_not:V \l__xcoolchap_titlestyle_tl }
            { \exp_not:V \l__xcoolchap_befchap_tl }
            { \exp_not:V \l__xcoolchap_afchap_tl }
            { \exp_not:V \l__xcoolchap_aftitle_tl }
        }
      \exp_last_unbraced:NV
    \group_end:
    \l__xcoolchap_redefinition_tl
}
\keys_define:nn { coolchap }
{
    chapstyle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_chapstyle_tl,
    titlestyle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_titlestyle_tl,
    befchap .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_befchap_tl,
    afchap .tl_set:N =  \l__xcoolchap_afchap_tl,
    aftitle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_aftitle_tl,
    chapstyle .initial:n = \HUGE\bfseries,
    titlestyle .initial:n = \Huge\bfseries,
    befchap .initial:n = 50,
    afchap .initial:n = 20,
    aftitle .initial:n = 180,
}



\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
    

    \coolchap[aftitle=36,befchap=10,afchap=40,chapstyle=\HUGE\itshape]
    
    \chapter{essai}
    
    XXX
    
    
\end{document}
```

---

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of `expkv-cs`*

Note that this is a lot easier with `expkv-cs` since it doesn't work with assignments and hence has no such grouping issues:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterformat}{mmmmm}{%
    \ifdef{\chapter}{%
        \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
            \vspace*{#3\p@}% Vertical Space before "Chapter X" (50)
            {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \reset@font
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                {#1 \@chapapp{} \thechapter} % Chapter-word formatting.
                \par
                \vskip #4\p@ % Vertical Space after "Chapter X" (20)
                \fi
                {#2 ##1} % Title formatting.
                \par\nobreak
                \vskip #5\p@}} % Vertical Space after Chapter Title (180)
    }{}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\coolchap{O{}}{\coolchapKV{#1}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\coolchapKV\chapterformat
  {
     chapstyle  = \HUGE\bfseries
    ,titlestyle = \Huge\bfseries
    ,befchap    = 50
    ,afchap     = 20
    ,aftitle    = 180
  }

\makeatother


\begin{document}
    

    \coolchap[aftitle=36,befchap=10,afchap=40,chapstyle=\HUGE\itshape]
    
    \chapter{essai}
    
    XXX
    
    
\end{document}
```

---

Output of both codes:

[image]

---

A different approach could be to just redefine `\chapterformat` and use your variables inside of that redefinition. That way you don't have to use any expansion tricks whatsoever and continue to use `l3keys`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{moresize}

\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ifdef{\chapter}{%
  \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]
    {%
      \vspace*{\l__xcoolchap_befchap_tl\p@}% Vertical Space before "Chapter X" (50)
      \begingroup
        \parindent \z@ \raggedright \reset@font
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          {\l__xcoolchap_chapstyle_tl \@chapapp{} \thechapter\par}% Chapter-word formatting.
          \vskip \l__xcoolchap_afchap_tl\p@ % Vertical Space after "Chapter X" (20)
        \fi
        {\l__xcoolchap_titlestyle_tl #1\par}% Title formatting.
        \nobreak
        \vskip \l__xcoolchap_aftitle_tl\p@
      \endgroup
    }% Vertical Space after Chapter Title (180)
}{}

\makeatother


\NewDocumentCommand{\coolchap}{O{}}
  { \keys_set:nn { coolchap } { #1 } }
\keys_define:nn { coolchap }
{
    chapstyle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_chapstyle_tl,
    titlestyle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_titlestyle_tl,
    befchap .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_befchap_tl,
    afchap .tl_set:N =  \l__xcoolchap_afchap_tl,
    aftitle .tl_set:N = \l__xcoolchap_aftitle_tl,
    chapstyle .initial:n = \HUGE\bfseries,
    titlestyle .initial:n = \Huge\bfseries,
    befchap .initial:n = 50,
    afchap .initial:n = 20,
    aftitle .initial:n = 180,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    

    \coolchap[aftitle=36,befchap=10,afchap=40,chapstyle=\HUGE\itshape]
    
    \chapter{essai}
    
    XXX
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670023/262813, `egreg`'s second proposal contains the redefinition inside the group and there is no issue?? I took it as a model and now I'm lost. Wow, `explkv-cs` literally takes two lines to create the command, it's tremendously impressive...

Comment: @VincentKrebs well, this is one of the places `expkv-cs` shines, for many other things `l3keys` is much better suited (the right tool for the right job and stuff... :) -- `expkv-cs` is brilliant to split a handful of keys into separate arguments and that's about it, for everything more complicated use either the general purpose key types in `expkv-def` or another nice solution like `l3keys`).

Comment: @VincentKrebs in that answer you don't want to redefine a macro but just use some `\draw` code. Note that this works inside of the group since Ti*k*Z is created in a way that it works with nested groups (e.g. its `scope` environment, or the `pic`s, or `node`s, etc.).

Comment: But what is nice with your package, is that the user can achieve something basic in a very simple way; it should always be like this, ideally. Without it, splitting arguments is *very* confusing for beginners like me. Thanks for the explanation, I understand, so that was a special case and now I should rather take this strategy as a general model. Don't want to sound simplistic, I know every case is different, but what I need right now is some marks, patterns that I can reproduce and assimilate.

Comment: @VincentKrebs The preferable approach would then be to do the redefinition and just use the key-values directly as in my last code block, and only resort to the splitting variant if that's really necessary. The reason why splitting arguments is not simple in most packages is that it's just rarely needed.

Comment: @VincentKrebs the `\let\split\ekvcSplitAndForward` is not a good idea, imho, you save a few characters and get possible incompatibilities with other code that relies on some `\split` macro.

Comment: `SplitAndFoward` doesn't sound too complicated, `ekvc` is just the naming-prefix of `expkv-cs` to avoid collisions.

Comment: @VincentKrebs if you're afraid of redefining `\@makechapterhead` then you shouldn't code your macro in the first place :P

Comment: @VincentKrebs maybe, but I find the caps easier to parse for my eyes, and there are also `\ekvcSplit` and `\ekvcSplitAndUse` (the last name of these is probably the most annoying one of these).

Comment: I realize, if I make the argument mandatory, which is my favourite approach (and I notice that the command even works with empty braces, using the defaults), then `\NewDocumentCommand\coolchap{O{}}{\coolchapKV{#1}}` is not even needed. Only 1 command to achieve what I need, thanks `expkv`.

Comment: `\split` is used in `amsmath`